# License for "Visual Studio Code" editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) below the download links there is a [link to the licence](https://code.visualstudio.com/license), which is some "MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS".  The product pages also reference it being "Free and open source" and point to a [github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), which has an a LICENSE.txt with the same MS license, but in the README it says MIT.  Which license is the correct one for "Visual Studio Code"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft's binary distribution of Code is under the Microsoft Software License, while the source on GitHub is under MIT. There's a more indepth explanation at [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005).